# Separation of Concerns and API Controllers in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to build my first enterprise **ASP.NET MVC 4** web application, and I'm having some issues figuring out the correct flow of things.

Let's say I have a view Clients.cshtml, which has the corresponding ClientsController, base class `Controller`.

I want the Clients view to display a list of all clients in the system.

Because of Separation of Concerns, I believe the correct place to handle such a request would be an `ApiController`, not the `Controller` itself, which I believe should be more or less restricted to UI tasks. So, I add the method `getClients()` in the `ApiController` which will return a JSON object containing all the clients.

Now, how do I consume this from my View, or my `Controller`?
A way, I believe, would be handling it using javascript; when the View is loaded, I call the `ApiController` using `jQuery` and such, and display the results asynchronically.

But I am not sure this is the correct approach, is it? I believe it is *one* approach, but I'd like to know alternatives, or better (more conventional) ways of handling this.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It isn't necesary to develop a Web API, if you won't use that API in other web apps or mobile apps.
A Web API is intended to be an easy way to have a single core for several consumers, for example android apps, iOS, web apps or even custom third party consumers.

So if your app won't be used that way you don't need to use API Controllers.

If you want to separate concerns, I recomend you to create a different project (a Class Library project) in the same solution, that project would be your internal API. Then your MVC project will consume your internal API, trying to keep your controllers as skin as possible. I recomend you to read [this article](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model) (it's for Ruby on Rails, but all the concepts apply to MVC .NET).

Comment: What about wanting to get the data using javascript? A class library wouldn't be the solution, what I'm wondering is the correct way to expose these services to be consumed either by javascript or plain C# code.

Comment: @SoManyGoblins your point is very valid. If your views contain Javascript which will make AJAX calls, you may want to expose a JSON API, even if you have no other consumers of said API.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you're looking for is a way to surface the same data to both your views (server-side rendering) and your javascript (through a JSON API).

There are multiple ways to go about this. As you mentioned, you could create a separate API controller, but in my experience this is a little smelly once you grow beyond a handful of API calls. Ideally, you'd want your API to have the same RESTful architecture as your normal controllers, which means you'd be repeating a lot of the same logic for adding, listing, and removing objects.

A good alternative I've found is to allow each controller to return either a view or JSON, depending on the format of the request. This could be expanded to include XML, CSV, or any other formats you'd like to consume from a client. There's an [excellent blog post](http://icanhascode.com/2009/05/simple-ror-respond_to-functionality-in-aspnet-mvc/) by [Michael Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133974/michael-morton) about this approach. It may not be exactly what you're looking for, but the end result looks something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Client> clients = db.Clients.ToList();
    return RespondTo(format =>
    {
        format.Html = () => View(clients);
        format.Json = () => Json(clients);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly what the ApiControllers do already, and out of the box :) the requests check the accepted content type, and return the data in the format requested, it's pretty cool; so requests by javascript that request JSON get JSON, and if for example you use your browser, you get XML by default, no C# additional code required for this behavior

Comment: That's a great point -- I wasn't aware of that functionality until recently.